# Cant intercept javascript callbacks when using cordova (3.x) plugin

Tags: ios, iphone, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am currently working with a cordova plugin which uses the AudioStreamer framework to control and stream audio. I am looking to intercept callbacks sent from the js portion of the plugin in the main javascript code in my application, for example 'pause_success'. When a calls the pause method of the plugin this:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window.plugins.stream.pause_success()')
    global code (index.html, line 1)
```

i have tried:

```
window.plugins.stream.pause_success = function(success){
    if(success){
        alert('success');
    }

};
```

which does nothing

and:

```
window.plugins.stream.pause_success(function (){
    if(success){
        alert('success');
    }

});
```

Which results in the following error

```
[Error] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    pause_success (StreamManager.js, line 60)
    etc etc
```

The code for the success callback on the plugin side is as follows:

```
StreamManager.prototype.pause_success = function(){
      if(this.pause_success){
        this.pause_success();
      }
    }
```

with the actual pause function as follows:

```
StreamManager.prototype.pause = function(options, success, fail){
  this.pause_success = success;
  this.pause_error = fail;
    cordova.exec(null, null, "Stream", "pause", [options]);
}
```

Does anyone know the correct way to intercept these callbacks or is it just something done improperly on the plugin side?

The plugin repository can be found here: https://github.com/feedhenry/fh-cordova-plugin-stream

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know this plugin, but as I understand it and as other plugins work, what it does is call the success and fail callback functions you defined in the call of the action function, so why do you want to intercept the callback?

Comment: Well for example, when audio successfully starts to play i wish to then update the apps controls, ditto with pause and when the song ends or errors out i want to call the next track and perform pre-fetch operations. Thats why i want to specify the callback behaviour in my main application :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding (but again I don't know this plugin) is that you should call the action function and pass it the name of the action, a callback to call in case of success and a callback to call in case of failure.

You don't need to modify the plugin's function or try to intercept the callback since the plugin calls the callback you specify.

For example it could look something like that:

```
function pauseSuccess(){
    alert("pause success!")
}
function pauseError(){
    alert("pause error!")
}
function pause(){
    StreamManager.action({act:'pause'},pauseSuccess,pauseError);
}
```

Comment: Ah an excellent suggestion! My only issue with this is that would be be done on the actual plugin's javascript logic side which doesn't have access to the main app's functions.

Comment: Not at all, this is the way calling plugins work. You do this in your app not in the plugin code. You give the plugin references to callback functions, and the plugin uses those reference to call the functions on completion.